# How to use a bash variable in python

Tags: python, linux, bash

In bash I'm able to do this  in bash`IP=$(wget -qO- ipinfo.io/ip)` This captures my public IP and stores it as the variable $IP on my Raspberry Pi.
Now I want to capture this variable in python to make a led connected to GPIO 1 turn on when the `$IP` is not equal to 82.1x.xxx.xx .
I'm kind of a newbie in python so I need some help, I have very little knowledge in python but very good knowledge in bash. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) dict. Try it out:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['IP']
```

or

```
>>> os.environ.get('IP')
```

From doc:

**os.environ**

> A mapping object representing the string environment. For example,
>   environ['HOME'] is the pathname of your home directory (on some
>   platforms), and is equivalent to getenv("HOME") in C.

**BONUS GAME**

You could grab IP from http response just using pure Python, something like this:

```
import urllib2
# that's really cool!
IP = urllib2.urlopen("http://ipinfo.io/ip").read().strip()
```

Comment: @LakhanMankani If you just need get environment var just use os.environ["SOME_VAR"] like mu above answer.