# accessing environment variable in python script when called from a shell script differs from running it in the shell directly

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script which is calling the python script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo python test.py
```

test.py is accessing some environment variable

```
os.getenv('MYKEY')
```

I get `None` when python script is being called from shell script. However it works fine if `test.py` is executed directly from the shell.

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a bash variable in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007026/how-to-use-a-bash-variable-in-python)

Comment: @EricRenouf, it's true. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` does not keep environment variables by default.

See [how to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo).

Here is what I did to reproduce your result.

```
$ export MYKEY=5
$ python test.py
5
$ sudo python test.py
None
```

Your shell script should give the same result if you use `python test.py` rather than `sudo python test.py`. If you still want to use `sudo`, then you would need to use `sudo -E bash -c 'python test.py'`.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly did not `export MYKEY` before invoking your shell script, so that shell script actually has no access to `MYKEY` and so the python script also has no access to it.